# Edit multer upload destination

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

i've been doing some research on **uploading with multer**, and it's working pretty well. And recently, i've been trying to enhance my current code so that **the upload destination can be chosen from the client side**. but it turn out to be a dead end.

**Is there any possible way to change the upload destination from the client side ?**

Here's the code i've been using as a base, it's pretty standard:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads'); //same folder as upload.js
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    // fileNameUploaded = file.originalname
    callback(null, Date.now()+ path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPhoto',5);

//upload file
router.post('/api/upload',function(req,res){
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed using something like that

```
const path = require('path')

destination: function (req, file, callback) {
  const dest = req.query.dest
  callback(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', dest))
},
```

it takes a url like `?dest=folder` and appends that to your upload path.

But if you let the client choose the directory make sure that `dest` cat not be something like `../` and will override files you dont want to be overwritten (like your upload.js).